# WPF How to bind from a DataTemplate inside a DataGridCell to the column header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `DataGrid` whose cells are all filled with buttons.
All the buttons are linked to the same command, however I would like to know in which column the button pressed is located, so I thought I would bind the button `CommandParameter` to the `Header` of the column.

Here is my View:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ModelList}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn}}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.NewCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.Resources>

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <control:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn x:Name="Test" Header="Powerbar" 
                                                         Binding="{Binding PowerBarModel}"
                                                         CellTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"
                                                         CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}">
                    </control:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn>
                    <control:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn Header="Circuit Breaker"
                                                         Binding="{Binding BreakerModel}"
                                                         CellTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"
                                                         CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}">
                    </control:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn>
                    <control:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn Header="Circuit Equipment"
                                                         Binding="{Binding EquipmentModel}"
                                                         CellTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"
                                                         CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}">
                    </control:DataGridBoundTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

And here is my ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : IDialogAware
    {
        public DelegateCommand<object> NewCommand { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {         
            NewCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(NewCommandExecute);
        }      

        private void NewCommandExecute(object commandParameter)
        {
            var detailItemList = new List<object>();

            if (commandParameter == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            switch (commandParameter)
            {
                case "Powerbar":
                {
                    detailItemList = PowerbarList;
                    break;
                }
                case "Circuit Breaker":
                {
                    detailItemList = BreakerList;
                    break;
                }
                case "Circuit Equipment":
                {
                    detailItemList = EquipmentList;
                    break;
                }
    }
```

However `CommandParameter` is always null. If I replace the binding with a static string (for example `CommandParameter="Test"`) then CommandParameter passes a value to `NewCommandExecute`, but not when I try to bind.

How do I bind the `CommandParameter` to the value of the column `Header`, so that I can identify which column holds the button that was clicked?

Thanks

Comment: DataGridColumns can't be target of a RelativeSource binding. They're no Framework(Content)Elements and dont belong to the visual tree.
There are workarounds. In your case the most easy way would be to just do `CommandParameter={Binding}` and in `NewCommandExecute` check for the type of the ViewModel passed in as `commandParameter` rather than the header string

Comment: Doesn't the row come into it somewhere? The details for the row? In which case why not put the detailed collections within a viewmodel represents each column in the item viewmodel.

Comment: @lidqy Thanks for the suggestion. It's a good solution but it is possible for two columns to return the same objects. I wouldn't be able to identify which column it came from solely by looking at the column binding.

Comment: @Andy yes each column is bound to the property of a parent object in an observable collection. The parent object is easy to get using the `DataGrid` `SelectedItem` property, but I would like to be able to know which of the object property I am interacting with.

Comment: What I'm saying is put that collection in an object the name is in. One object per column. Then it's always just the generic name collection. No need for a parameter. Kind of the point of a viewmodel is to adapt data to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGridColumn` itself is not part of the visual tree. It's a placeholder template that logically groups cells and describes how they are rendered.
After all its bindings for the cell and cell editing views are resolved the column object itself is "replaced" by a `DataGridCell` to represent (render) the actual value (content) of the cell.
This means all your cell layout elements are actually a child of the individual `DataGridCell`.

That's why you must focus to get the current `DataGridCell`.
Because `DataGridCell` is a `ContentControl` and the cell's view a direct child of the `DataGridCell`, the templated parent of the cell content (`DataTemplate`) is a `ContentPresenter` (located in the `ControlTemplate` of the `DataGridCell`).

To pass the column's header to the `CommandParameter` you must adjust the source and path of the `Binding` as follows:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
  <Button CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                     Path=(ContentPresenter.Parent).(DataGridCell.Column).Header}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

As an alternative you can always inline the `DataTemplate` and hardcode the column's header as local property value.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation!
It seems like it should do what I'm looking to achieve, however it seems to always return `null`.
`Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` does return a `ContentPresenter` so I looked at its properties and noticed the `ContentPresenter` `Parent` is `null`. Would you know why that is?

Comment: You can try to only bind to the templated parent: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` and in your command handler you use the `VisualTreeHelper` to get to the `DataGridCell` parent by traversing the visual tree: `var header = ((VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(commandParameter as ContentPresenter) as FrameworkElement).TemplatedParent as DataGridCell).Column.Header;`. The `FrameworkElement.Parent` property will reference the logical tree parent. For some reason it is disconnected in your scenario. When I setup a simple `DataGrid` it works for me (both solutions work for me).